# On React Mui lib , Why `AppBar, Toolbar` element child use `display` not work?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to learn frontend develop.

Why AppBar element child use `display` not work? I want to understand the what happen.

This my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-violet-jk8zr7?from-embed=&file=/index.js

My question one, on `<AppBar/>` I want to show two elements on two line by `display:'block'`, but it does not work.

My question two, on `<Toolbar/>` I want to show two elements on one line by `display:'inline'`, but it does not work.

I want to understand what is happening. I'm a frontend newbie.